# Outlook VSTO crashes at around 800MB with UCEERR_RENDERTHREADFAILURE

Tags: c#, memory, visual-studio-2013, outlook, vsto

I am observing that my Outlook VSTO keeps slow and steady memory increase (as per Task Manager).

Using VS2013, Outlook 2013, C#

Windows 10, 64bits, with 16GB RAM and over 130GB disk space.

Reviewing my app logs I found that I am getting

```
UCEERR_RENDERTHREADFAILURE (Exception from HRESULT: 0X88980406)
at System.Windows.Media.composition.DUCE.Channel.SyncFlush()
```

Looking at the dmp files created by procdump, I can see that I have probably both high memory consumption and memory leak which seem to be more prominent.

I find that investigating dmp files is very time consuming job.  I wonder if VS2013 can work with FastMM or some other tool to investigate for memory leaks.

As I am new to Visual Studio, I wonder if someone can recommend any useful tools when dealing with memory leaks that work well with Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Does your computer have more than 400 MB of memory?

Comment: yes, updated post.  thanks